# GET parameter in a POST <form>

Tags: php, forms, post, action

is it possible to put some post input values to a 'action' url?

For example:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php">
<input type="text" name="username">
<input type="submit">
</form>
```

The resulting URL is index.php but I want to add name's value at the end of url like this:

```
index.php?name=value
```

I don't want to change from 'post' to 'get'.

Comment: Can't you just add it to the `action=` part of your form?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to post form, do as you did already. You can also add `GET` parameters in `action`, like:

```
<form method="post" action="index.php?name=value">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

It is also possible to dynamically change `action` before posting.

You can achieve it with something like that:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function changeAction() {
  this.action += '&other=value';
}
</script>

<form method="post" action="index.php?name=value" onsubmit="changeAction()">
  <input type="text" name="username">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```

(not tested)

Answer (score 0):

You can dynamically add the form's action by adding the username value with javascript/jQuery on form submit.

Answer (score 0):

You can also place `input type='hidden'` in your form holding the values you want to POST but not to present on the form